# Defining a letter as a character

Tags: c

Basically what i'm trying to do is to define letters as a number so if i give a letter to my program it treats it like a normal number.

I tried to do it using this code but it doesn't seem to work: If you have any suggestions i'd be thankful.

```
         #include<stdio.h>

        int main()
        {


    #define F 10

    int liczba;

    scanf("%d",liczba);

    printf("%d",liczba);

    }

I also tried to define it using the loop but then i was getting an error

        #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 10; i<32; i++)
    {

#define '55+i' i


    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: `scanf("%d",liczba);` should be `scanf("%d",&liczba);`. Also when you mean letter as a number, do you mean "2" (ASCII) to 2 (DECIMAL), or the ASCII decimal representation of that character?

Comment: You guys are right. My question sucks. I ll ask better next time. What i'm trying to do is to define Numbers from A - Z starting A - 10,B-11 and so on. So i could enter a letter and program treats it as a defined number

Comment: There are many ways of doing this i.e. Lookup table, conditional statements etc. Your best bet is to explore the foundations of C before embarking on this task. Understand how arrays, loops, conditional statements etc. work. This is a fairly straight forward task but understanding the basics is essential first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input to be a letter,then you need a `char` variable instead of an `int`:

```
#include<stdio.h>        
    int main()
    {  
    char liczba; //char variable
    scanf("%c",&liczba); //%c for a character
    printf("%d",liczba); //prints the ASCII value of the character    
    }
```

I read the comments and you said that you need A=10,B=11 etc. In that case,use

```
if(liczba>='A' && liczba <='Z')
  printf("%d",(liczba-'A')+10);
```

The `if` is required to check if the input is between A and Z.